# sequelize Postgres can I order by updatedAt

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am in Node.js with Postgres, db.findAll I want to order the data by udpatedAt Desc, but
order: [["updatedAt", "DESC"]] does not work, updatedAt is not column name, is added by model automatically

Comment: from datagrip select * from conversations order by conversations."updatedAt" desc; this return normal and correctly

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you solve issues, but there are certain expected elements your question needs to contain to enable this. Please take a few minutes to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com) and review [ask]. Afterwards update your question to contain: table definition (ddl), exact query, exact result (complete), sample data (as text - **no images**), and the expected results of that data.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason, the updatedAt for all the items are the same in my DB, that is why it is not working. sorry and Thanks